# How to show convergence of Frank-Wolfe algorithm ( or conditional gradient method)?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $g(w)$ be a differentiable convex function. Frank-Wolfe algorithm over a convex set $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined so as to find the local minimum of the function:

$$ 
s_{t+1}=\arg\min_{s \in C} \langle s, \nabla g(w_t) \rangle \tag{1}
$$
$$
w_{t+1} = (1-\eta_t)w_{t}+\eta_ts_t \tag{2}
$$

where $\eta_t$ is the step size and is in $[0,1]$ and $t=1,2,\cdots,T$.

The intuition behind the the first step of Frank-Wolfe algorithm is that we find the closest vector to the negative gradient (by closest I mean the projection of $s_{t+1}$ onto $-\nabla g(w_t)$ is maximum). The intuition behind the second step arises from the fact that we start off from $s_1$ which is in $C$ and chose $w_{1}$ so as to be in $C$ using the convex combination.

I have drawn the following picture to better understanding.

[image]

Note: If $C$ was a polytope, then $s_1$ is at the vertex of the polytpoe because $(1)$ became Linear Programming.

My questions are:

1- Why this works?

2- What is the proof of convergence?

3- When $-\nabla g(w_t)$ is not in $C$, why $s_{t+1}$ is on the boundary of $C$?

Comment: This [blog post](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2018/notes-on-the-frank-wolfe-algorithm-part-i/) has a section on convergence theory of the FW algorithm that may help answer your question.